# Alternative solution to a problem involving an enumeration of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, rational-numbers

I'm working on the same problem as in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119309/enumeration-of-rationals-from-stein-shakarchi). I understand the solutions provided in the answers. The question basically asks us to find an enumeration of the rationals $\{r_n\}_{n≥1}$ such that the complement of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(r_{n}-\frac{1}{n},r_{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is non-empty.

I found the solutions rather complicated. What's wrong with my approach? For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $r_n = 2^{n^2}$. This way, I know $[-\infty,1)$ is in the complement of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(r_{n}-\frac{1}{n},r_{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$. Doesn't that complete the problem? What did I miss?

Comment: Well, you did not enumerate all rationals!

Comment: @Mindlack Oops. I didn't know that we needed to have *all* the rationals.

Comment: The question is confusing.  Any numeration of the rationals usually lists positive numbers, so the negative numbers would not be covered in any union.  I suspect the original question would include negative rationals, or else getting a complement in $R_+$..

Comment: @Mindlack Why not an official answer?